# What do opcodes 0xE9 (JP HL) and 0xF8 (LD HL,SP+r8) do?

Tags: emulation, gameboy, opcodes

I think I am struggling to define correctly the following ambiguous opcodes: `LD HL,SP+r8` and `JP (HL)` opcodes (`0xE9` and `0xF8` respectively)

In my implementation, `LD HL,SP+r8` sets `HL` to the value of `SP+r8`, but I have a feeling that it may be to do with loading memory from RAM.
`JP (HL)`, I have as `PUSH`ing the PC onto the stack and setting the Program Counter to the value of HL (like `JP a16`, except with the value of HL), but I've read a few forums that seem to say that that's wrong.

**Any clarification of what either of these instructions do would be great, as I'm pretty lost at the moment.**

Comment: maybe this helps you somehow [0xE9](https://github.com/drhelius/Gearboy/blob/master/src/opcodes.cpp#L1700) and [0xF8](https://github.com/drhelius/Gearboy/blob/master/src/opcodes.cpp#L1799)

Comment: @Dodge I've been looking for an open source emulator to see what the source is, but the only one I found implemented some opcodes entirely wrong so I didn't really trust it. Has this emulator been tested? If so, thank you, you've been very helpful!

Comment: You can checkout mine https://github.com/creker/Cookieboy It passes all blargg's tests - CPU, timings, LCD, sound. Even those that test hardware bugs

Comment: @creker thanks, as I said it's been pretty hard to find an open source emulator that actually works. Just gotta sort through all those files now. ^~^ But that'll only take a few minutes, so thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my implementation, LD HL,SP+r8 sets HL to the value of SP+r8, but I have a feeling that it may be to do with loading memory from RAM.

No. It just takes an 8-bit immediate, sign-extends it, adds the value of `SP` to it and stores the result in `HL`.

> JP (HL), I have as PUSHing the PC onto the stack and setting the Program Counter to the value of HL (like JP a16, except with the value of HL)

`JP` doesn't push the current `PC` on the stack (maybe you're confusing it with `CALL`). What `JP (HL)` does is just `PC = HL`.